# Workday soap api - Get_Candidates operation

Tags: workday-api

I'm starting to work on workday integration, when my first purpose is to retrieve all candidates\applicants that currently exist.

I copied the "Get_Candidates_Request" xml from the official documentation site (https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Recruiting/v33.1/samples/Get_Candidates_Request.xml), fixed it so it will be valid (using soapui), but  I'm still getting "invalid request" as response...

Does anyone ever worked with this operation and can give me a hand? What do I miss??

> SOAP-ENV:Client.validationError
>            Invalid request

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without seeing that fixed up request, but here's a quick example of a request that would retrieve all candidates that applied after the first of the year. I hope that this able to get your moving in the right direction.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>true</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Get_Candidates_Request bsvc:version="v33.0">
         <bsvc:Request_Criteria>            
            <bsvc:Applied_From>2019-01-01T00:00:00</bsvc:Applied_From>
         </bsvc:Request_Criteria>         
      </bsvc:Get_Candidates_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi @rihacek and thanks for your answer. I'm afraid the "invalid request" was result of incorrect endpoint I addressed. Now, after I fixed the endpoint I receiving the following: `<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.authenticationError</faultcode>
         <faultstring>tenant is temporarily unavailable due to server patching</faultstring>` . Any ideas?

Comment: @MayaMarton I've only ever seen that as an error indicating that I had a typo in the tenant name. Make sure that your tenant is spelled correctly _which includes case_. **ThisTenant** is not the same as **thistenant**.

Comment: thanks very much @rihacek. Your example worked perfectly, the problem was in the user permissions...